# Float to int in Apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file which I am processing using apache pig. I have a chararray field which I am casting to float, if the value of that field is less than 0, I want to make it integer 0 and if it is greater than zero, then keep the float number as it is.

For ex: if number is -1234.56, make it integer 0. If number is 2345.67, keep it 2345.67

I am failing using the following code, Output is coming 0.0 and I want 0, due to which my job is failing. Please help.!

```
((float)field_name > 0 ? (float)field_name:(int)0) AS field_name,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields in Pig (such as `field_name`) must contain only values of the same type, such as all float or all int. When you run the code above, Pig automatically converts the int `0` to the float `0.0` since `field_name` must be able to take on float values like `2345.67`. You probably got the warning `Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_FLOAT` - this is why. I'd recommend reworking the rest of your code so that an output of `0.0` doesn't cause the job to fail.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will look into this.!

Answer (score 1):

@savagedata is correct, you can't have field with differently typed values. But if you want to see `0` instead of `0.0` I suggest you converting field to string based on your condition.